# build command-line-arguments: cannot load local package: cannot find module providing package

Tags: go, go-modules, go-micro

I am unable to load local package using go mod. I have seperate go.mod files for repoA and repoB. I have found no solution anywhere. OS is windows.

```
$> go version
go version go1.12.7 windows/amd64
```

I have two modules with repository, when I run main file from **repoA**. It will try to find module/package of **repoB**, then it throws an error saying

> cannot find module providing package

My repo structure :-

```
����repoA
�   ����proto
�   �   ����system
�   ����sauth
�   ����shandle
�   ����smodel
�   ����sresponse
����repoB
    ����common
    ����config
    ����proto
        ����account
        ����auth
        ����session
```

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I too get same error in intellij IDE with go plugin

Answer (score 0):

How does the `go.mod` file of `repoA` look?

Imports should always be absolute, e.g.:

```
import "github.com/Himanshu/repoB"
```

Then, in `repoA`'s `go.mod` file you can add a `replace` directive to point "github.com/Himanshu/repoB" to a local path (could be relative).

Make sure to read the relevant parts of the [Modules wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) and the [official blog post on modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)

Answer (score 0):

After doing couple of things the issue got resolved with my IntelliJ.

1. Initialize the go module in the project and
2. Refer package with absolute path.

I have 2 folders -> repoA and repoB which are present in folder c:\goprograms. Run `go mod init examplegoprogram.com/app`. Now, I see go.mod file in goprograms folder with content `module examplegoprogram.com/app`. In repoA, you can now refer repoB as `import "examplegoprogram.com/app/repoB"`

If you are using new Intellij Ultimate, enable go modules under Project settings `Alt + Ctrl + S` Languages & Frameworks -> Go -> Go Modules